# Как лучше сделать так что бы в WebView при нажатии на изображение оно открывалось поверх WebView на всю ширину экрана

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-webview

Имеется `WebView`, в котором отображается контент с сайта.

Пытаюсь сделать так, что-бы при нажатии на картинку в `WebView` она открывалась на переднем плане на всю ширину экрана.

Эту картинку потом можно было увеличивать раздвигая пальцами либо двойным кликом на ней (для этого использую кастомизированный `ImageView`).

`WebView` должен быть на втором плане виден, затенен и неактивен.

При тапе на поле за картинкой - картинка исчезает и `WebView` возвращается  на передний план.

При клике на изображение получаю его адрес и гружу с помощью `Picasso` в `ImageView`.

Пробовал при клике на картинку открывать новое `Activity` и задавать ему стиль диалога. Но, остаются закругленные углы. И серые поля сверху и снизу картинки если она имеет небольшую высоту. К тому же диалоговое окно не расширяется динамично при раздвигании картинки.

Так же пробовал использовать `ConstraintLayout` для того, что-бы открыть  `ImageView` поверх `WebView` в том же `Activity`. Но, не могу вывести `ImageView` поверх `Webview` так, чтобы `Webview` был статичен и затенен.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше это реализовать не городя тучу костылей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения даного вопроса использовал библиотеку от MikeOrtiz  - [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView).

В `xml` где лежит моя `webView` добавил `ConstraintLayout`, которому назначил атрибут `android:visibility="gone"` в нем добавил  кастомное `view` использовав библиотеку  [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

При клике на изображение в `webView`получаю изображение и загружаю его в кастомное `View`, далее делаю `Layout` с этим `View` видимым.

Библиотека дает возможность скалировать изображение. А использование `Layout` с атрибутом 
`android:background="#C8000000"` дает нужное затемнение.